# How to adjust zoom level in react-leaflet based on the coordinates of the polygons

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-leaflet

I am trying to create a map with polygons. How can we determine the zoom level so that all polygons are visible on the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FeatureGroup](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#featuregroup) for that. Something like this:

```js
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
    '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
    'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(mymap);

var poly1 = L.polygon([
  [51.509, -0.08],
  [51.503, -0.06],
  [51.51, -0.047]
]).addTo(mymap);

var poly2 = L.polygon([
  [51.519, -0.18],
  [51.513, -0.16],
  [51.52, -0.147]
]).addTo(mymap);

var group = L.featureGroup([poly1, poly2]);

mymap.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
```